Multithreading and scheduling Java
Please tell me how best to do it: I have many objects, about 200, that update their state from the network once every 20 seconds (similar to a web page that is being refreshed). Each object has several observers/subscribers, and as soon as an object has no observers it stops updating and the object ceases to exist.
I haven’t come up with anything like launching a separate thread for each object, updating it in a loop and sleeping for 20 seconds. And then when the last observer signs off, change the flag interrupt and use it to complete the thread.
public class Controller implements Runnable {
    ...
    public void run() {
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " start control: " + page.getUri().toString());
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                notificationNewEvent(page.refreshEvents());
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.info("Thread is stop. ID:{}, Name: {}", page.getZip(), page.getTitle());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}


While mutithreading can help in getting updates from webpages in a more timely way, I recommend you use a single threaded messaging service for notifications.

I do not know about the best way to do it. But I can show you one way to do it. Perhaps this will give ideas to use in your own final implementation.
Represent your 200 objects being observed as a Publisher class.
package work.basil.example.threading.pubsub;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Publisher
{
    public final int id;
    private Instant content = Instant.now( );
    private final Collection < Subscriber > subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList <>(  );

    public Publisher ( final int id ) { this.id = id; }

    public void publish ( final Instant content )
    {
        this.content = content;
        try (
                final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor( )
        )
        {
            this.subscribers.forEach( subscriber ->
            {
                executorService.submit( ( ) -> subscriber.onPublication( this ) );
            } );
        }
    }

    public Instant getContent ( ) { return this.content; } // `Instant` is immutable, so our content here is thread-safe.

    public void addSubscriber ( final Subscriber subscriber ) { this.subscribers.add( subscriber ); }

    public void removeSubscriber ( final Subscriber subscriber ) { this.subscribers.remove( subscriber ); }

    public List < Subscriber > getSubscribers ( ) { return List.copyOf( this.subscribers ); }
}

Define the class for Subscriber. All we need for this demo is a method to be called each time a publication occurs.
package work.basil.example.threading.pubsub;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Subscriber
{
    public final UUID id ;

    public Subscriber ( final UUID id ) { this.id = id; }

    public void onPublication ( final Publisher publisher) {
        // Retrieve new content being published by the publisher.
        Instant newContent = publisher.getContent();

        // Simulate work being done to consume content.
        long randomMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( 200, 1_200);
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( randomMillis) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }

        System.out.println("At " + Instant.now() + " Subscriber id: "+ this.id + " consumed new content: " + newContent + " from publisher id: " + publisher.id );
    }
}

Define the task to run every 20 seconds.
The job of this task is to loop each of the publishers. Each publisher is inspected. If the publisher has no more subscribers, we remove it from our list of publishers. To make our demo work, we also randomly drop a subscriber, though this is a hack and not a part of your business logic.
For each publisher with remaining subscribers, we loop the subscribers. For each subscriber, we create a task, submitting that task to a local executor service. Each of those subscribers receive the published information on a separate thread, all doing their subscription business concurrently.
You also asked about phasing out this repeating publishing cycle after no more publisher remained, after all subscribers have been removed. We signal that condition via a ReentrantLock object passed in to the constructor.
package work.basil.example.threading.pubsub;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class PublicationCycle implements Runnable
{
    private final Collection < Publisher > publishers;
    private final ReentrantLock publishingLock;

    public PublicationCycle ( final Collection < Publisher > publishers , final ReentrantLock publishingLock )
    {
        this.publishers = publishers;
        this.publishingLock = publishingLock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at " + Instant.now( ) );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor( ) ;
        )
        {
            if ( !this.publishingLock.isLocked( ) ) this.publishingLock.lock( );
            this.publishers.forEach( publisher -> {
                // For purpose of our demo, randomly drop a subscriber.
                if ( ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextBoolean( ) )
                {
                    Subscriber subscriber = publisher.getSubscribers( ).getLast( );
                    publisher.removeSubscriber( subscriber );  // May not be a subscriber any longer if another thread removed it during the moment between these two lines of code.
                }
                if ( publisher.getSubscribers( ).isEmpty( ) )
                {
                    publishers.remove( publisher );  // Drop any publisher with no subscribers.
                } else
                {
                    executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
                        // Retrieve new content.
                        // Simulate a blocking network call (for information retrieval) by sleeping this thread.
                        long randomMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( 50 , 400 );
                        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( randomMillis ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
                        Instant content = Instant.now( );  // Our simulated new content.

                        // Publish the new content we obtained.
                        publisher.publish( content );
                    } );
                }
            } );
            if ( this.publishers.isEmpty( ) ) this.publishingLock.unlock( ); // Signals the originating thread that we need not continue scheduling this task. All done.
        }
        System.out.println( "INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

Put this code to work in an App class.
A ScheduledExecutorService is instantiated to periodically execute this publication cycle. By "periodically", we mean every 20 seconds as stated in your Question.
Notice how we instantiate the lock here, but do not lock it. The lock needs to be set on the other thread, not the current thread. Then further down here we wait a moment, giving enough time for the background thread to set the lock. Then we try to acquire the lock, which results in blocking until that lock becomes available. This is how the background thread signals to this thread that its work is complete, and no more scheduling of the ScheduledExecutorService is needed.
Important: See how we gracefully shut down the ScheduledExecutorService here. This is vital, as the background threads may continue indefinitely, even past the end of your app, like zombies ‍♂️. Always gracefully shutdown your executor services. The other executor services seen above were automatically closed via try-with-resources syntax.
package work.basil.example.threading.pubsub;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "BEWARE: Output on console does *not* necessarily appear in chronological order when called from across threads. " );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo start at " + Instant.now( ) );

        // Dummy data for publishers.
        final int COUNT_PUBLISHERS = 3;  // Or 200 per the original Question on Stack Overflow.
        Collection < Publisher > publishers =
                // Using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as a thread-safe `List` implementation.
                new CopyOnWriteArrayList <>(
                        IntStream
                                .rangeClosed( 1 , COUNT_PUBLISHERS )
                                .mapToObj( Publisher :: new )
                                .toList( )
                );

        // Dummy data for subscribers.
        final int MINIMUM_INITIAL_SUBSCRIBERS_PER_PUBLISHER = 2;
        final int MAXIMUM_INITIAL_SUBSCRIBERS_PER_PUBLISHER = 5;
        publishers.forEach( publisher -> {
            int randomCountOfSubscribers = ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( MINIMUM_INITIAL_SUBSCRIBERS_PER_PUBLISHER , MAXIMUM_INITIAL_SUBSCRIBERS_PER_PUBLISHER );
            for ( int index = 0 ; index < randomCountOfSubscribers ; index++ )
            {
                publisher.addSubscriber( new Subscriber( UUID.randomUUID( ) ) );
            }
        } );

        // Schedule our publishers to publish every 20 seconds.
        final ReentrantLock publishingLock = new ReentrantLock( ); // Signal to continue publishing.
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor( );
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new PublicationCycle( publishers , publishingLock ) ,
                0,
                20 ,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
        );
        // Give enough time for the task in the other thread to lock our `publishingLock`.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds(3) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        publishingLock.lock( ); // Blocks until the task on the background thread determines no longer any need to run.
        scheduledExecutorService.close( );

        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo end at " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

Here is an example run. To keep it simple, we use only 3 publishers rather than your 200. And we start with 2-4 subscribers per publisher, eventually reduced to zero.
Notice how the number of subscribers is gradually reduced as we randomly remove them. Ditto for publishers.
BEWARE: Output on console does *not* necessarily appear in chronological order when called from across threads. 
INFO - Demo start at 2024-05-23T03:51:51.428822Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:51:51.454828Z
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.004225Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.786694Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.090102Z Subscriber id: 05c3cb7d-2559-4dd0-b9f4-339ee9b58ff0 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.627349Z from publisher id: 2
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.110528Z Subscriber id: ed4936b5-e008-4f7d-b15b-a1115dcf06c4 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.741222Z from publisher id: 1
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.407016Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.786694Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.593968Z Subscriber id: a90d9738-cc6a-4417-a7d6-13606367006b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.741222Z from publisher id: 1
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.662275Z Subscriber id: e25262c2-ae3b-4134-8b43-e1996acca486 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.627349Z from publisher id: 2
At 2024-05-23T03:51:52.904405Z Subscriber id: 77b02efb-0b09-4029-add6-5a732ee1611c consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:51:51.786694Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:51:52.904921Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:11.456370Z
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.066017Z Subscriber id: ed4936b5-e008-4f7d-b15b-a1115dcf06c4 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.835780Z from publisher id: 1
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.257065Z Subscriber id: 77b02efb-0b09-4029-add6-5a732ee1611c consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.553132Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.540062Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.553132Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.641477Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.553132Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.852889Z Subscriber id: e25262c2-ae3b-4134-8b43-e1996acca486 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.725692Z from publisher id: 2
At 2024-05-23T03:52:12.853698Z Subscriber id: 05c3cb7d-2559-4dd0-b9f4-339ee9b58ff0 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:11.725692Z from publisher id: 2
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:12.855937Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:31.459775Z
At 2024-05-23T03:52:32.390212Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:31.591769Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:32.422036Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:31.591769Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:32.534852Z Subscriber id: 77b02efb-0b09-4029-add6-5a732ee1611c consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:31.591769Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:32.849826Z Subscriber id: e25262c2-ae3b-4134-8b43-e1996acca486 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:31.775485Z from publisher id: 2
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:32.851076Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:51.455308Z
At 2024-05-23T03:52:52.495798Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:51.799613Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:52.702014Z Subscriber id: 77b02efb-0b09-4029-add6-5a732ee1611c consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:51.799613Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:52:52.911359Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:52:51.799613Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:52:52.911755Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:11.455028Z
At 2024-05-23T03:53:12.172225Z Subscriber id: 77b02efb-0b09-4029-add6-5a732ee1611c consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:11.793695Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:53:12.277279Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:11.793695Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:53:12.341305Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:11.793695Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:12.341962Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:31.459814Z
At 2024-05-23T03:53:32.241994Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:31.564146Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:53:32.365980Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:31.564146Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:32.368013Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:51.457112Z
At 2024-05-23T03:53:51.798523Z Subscriber id: 8e76afd3-3b8e-4885-8149-884484434db5 consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:51.543647Z from publisher id: 3
At 2024-05-23T03:53:52.104756Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:53:51.543647Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:53:52.105283Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:11.458505Z
At 2024-05-23T03:54:11.956815Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:54:11.710500Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:11.958844Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:31.458843Z
At 2024-05-23T03:54:32.196090Z Subscriber id: 5150168e-2261-4d8f-9560-68e6fb04ff8b consumed new content: 2024-05-23T03:54:31.789141Z from publisher id: 3
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:32.197014Z
INFO - Start `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:51.459425Z
INFO - End `run` method of `PublicationCycle` at 2024-05-23T03:54:51.460062Z
INFO - Demo end at 2024-05-23T03:54:51.462021Z

